# Closest form append doesnt work

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code:

```
$(".searchBtn").closest('form').submit(function () {
   $(this).find('.showComments tr:last').after("<tr><td>TEST</td></tr>");
});
```

and I have a

```
<form>
<div>
<table class="showComments"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="searchBtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

in my HTML page.

However, this code doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Joel

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: probably $this refers to .searchBtn rather than .form, have you checked that?

Comment: @Lina - `$(this)` refers to the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me. Maybe you just need to throw in a `return false`?

http://jsfiddle.net/h7WCv/